# How can I get the emails of all of a users friends from Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I have seen iphone apps that allow you to 'import your contacts from facebook'. Somehow they manage to get your friends emails.

I tried querying the facebook database with FQL and I only get back my own email (I DO have the email permission enabled).

How is it that the iphone app is able to get my friends emails as well? Scraping?

Comment: Can you name one of the iPhone apps? Facebook tries hard to never give out email addresses....

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Facebook friends' email?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4331666/how-to-get-facebook-friends-email) and/or [Facebook friends email FQL](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5114784/facebook-friends-email-fql)

Comment: The app is called smartr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal Facebook api does not support this.  Facebook could have whitelisted an app to allow for this but I am guessing they whitelist very few apps for this.